# HTML5 Video loadeddata event does not work in IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am trying to trigger an event once a video has loaded the first frame. The code I have used works in desktop browsers that I have tested in but it does not work in mobile safari on IOS. Is there something about the code that is not supported on mobile safari or is there another solution to achieve what I want?

```
function loadvideo (vidsource){

var vid = document.createElement('video');
vid.src = vidsource;

alert("Video about to load"); //This works fine in mobile safari
vid.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
alert("Video Loaded!"); //This does not display in mobile safari
//Will do something else here
}, false);

}
```

Comment: my guess is that you aren't calling loadvideo from a click or touchend event handler

Comment: So is there a way I can imitate this? As the video will not be displayed on the screen (only a thumbnail) so there is no way for the user to initiate

Comment: AFAIK, as long as the user is clicking anywhere (doesn't have to be clicking on the video), it's OK to load the video

Answer (score 11):

On iOS, it looks like the video doesn't get loaded unless the user hits play, or if the autoplay attribute has been added (which doesn't actually appear to autoplay it).

The following should work for you:

```
var vid = document.createElement('video');
if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent))
    vid.autoplay = true;
vid.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {[...]}, false);
vid.src = videosource;
```

Alternatively, you can listen to the `progress` event instead of `loadeddata`, which seems to work fine on iOS Safari.

Comment: but wouldn't the autoplay let always play the video?

Comment: Not sure about the autoplay part, but the `progress` event does indeed work everywhere. You can add `{ once: true }` instead of `false` to get the first frame.

Answer (score 7):

Add `preload="metadata"` to video tag and then listen to `loadedmetadata` event. It works in IOS Safari as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

try not to use `addEventListener` is this case, use older `on` style, AND set src AFTER you setup an event listener:

```
...
vid.onloadeddata = function () {
    alert("Video Loaded!");
    // do something
}
vid.src = vidsource;
...
```

If an EventListener is added to an EventTarget while it is processing an event, it will not be triggered by the current actions but may be triggered during a later stage of event flow, such as the bubbling phase. - To learn more - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Works in desktop browsers but does not work in mobile safari browser. I am making a mobile web app so it is crucial that it works on mobile safari browser

Comment: try to check your video mime types, maybe brouser can't understand it. This video will work on iPhone - `<video loop autoplay controls="true" width='100%' height='100%' src='//some_video.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>`- more here https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html

Comment: They are videos direct from a persons camera roll. The user uploads them. So they are 100% compatible

Comment: Could this be due to the fact that Apple have disabled all events until the user actually plays the video?

Comment: realy, i don't know that, but you can try to check it, all can be possible